How can I focus on an input in Android without the keyboard appearing?
I have a device running the Android operating system, and at the bottom of my device, there is a QR scanner. The device will be installed in a restaurant's kitchen. Its purpose is to display orders placed by the waiters and print a receipt when the order is started. Once the receipt is printed, I need to capture the QR data when the QR code on the receipt is scanned. I created an input for this and set its opacity to 0. As soon as the page opens, I set focus on the input, but when I do this, the system keyboard appears, causing an unpleasant display. How can I prevent this keyboard from appearing?
I am developing my application with Flutter SDK, but I can also use kotlin code to solve my problem.
i first tried focusing on the input and then closing the keyboard, but when I wrote the code to close the keyboard, it closed the keyboard but also lost focus, so I can't retrieve the QR value.

See this article which discusses how to avoid showing the keyboard when input field is focused: https://xabaras.medium.com/android-edittext-avoid-showing-software-keyboard-on-focus-10ada7f69628

does the scanner require an "input field"? If so, does it even need to be visible? You could set View.INVISIBLE or View.GONE and the field may still do what you want without the keyboard being involved.

do you need this keyboard? if this is "your" device then just disable keyboard... or wrote a simple keyboard app (from some tutorial) and set its height to 0/1 or make invisible and floating ("never-changing-Activitys-size", I've seen some can do this at least on tablets/big screens)

already exists :) nokeyboard also in GP store

If you use flutter and use TextFormField or TextField widget, there is a property called keyboardType to set your keyboard type. For setting prevent the keyboard show when the field is on focus set keyboardType: TextInputType.none.
Code example
TextFormField(
  controller: _yourController,
  // [keyboardType] properties for setting keyboard appearance,
  // set it to [TextInputType.none] will hide the keyboard.
  keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
),

